# How to get time from ios datepicker in 12 hour format with AM , PM?

Tags: iphone, ios

I m using date picker in my project and I m getting selected date as 24 hour format after applying format attribute as hh:mm . I can get 12 hour format date from by converting it using conditions but I want to know some direct method to get 12 hour format time from date picker with AM , PM . If anybody knows shortest way to do it then please indicate me by your answer. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have made a method for this , try it

```
-(NSString*)getTimetoFill
{
 NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

 NSString *timetofill = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:datepicker.date];
 return timetofill;
}
```